# Adding link to child node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add link in child nodes to navigate them on click. This is the code

```
var a_child = {
    parent: parent,
    text: { name: "a_child" }
};
```

Kindly help me in this

Comment: Help you on what exactly ?

Comment: can u explain clearly and tell what have u tried?

Comment: Adding link into it. Like I want to add a href in it so when I click on it, It will me to some other page.

Comment: I am making a hierarchical tree using js. So I have to use variables in javascript. I am succeding in it but I want to add more attributes in that variable beside the text only. Attribute like link to some other page.

Comment: Hi @FaizanKhokhar. There seems to be a little bit of a confusion of levels here. The code you've posted is agnostic of links/hrefs/page navigation etc. It's just a JS object, which by itself doesn't interact with the DOM in any way. Perhaps you have some surrounding code that uses a UI library or the DOM API. If you add that to your question it'd be easier to see what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting time of everybody. I found an answer to this question by several hit and tries method.

var someVariable = {

```
parent: parentVariable,
text: { name: "My Variable" },
link: { href: "http://www.some_link.com"}
```

};

SO when I click on the node which points to this variable, it will lead me to the given link.